Search for a lawyer by name in the US across states?
I have a lawyer's name and I'm trying to find if the person is a real licensed lawyer in the US. For some reasons I cannot ask the person directly at this moment, so I'm asking here.
I do not know which state the person is licensed in, is there a way I can search for the person easily without going to 50 state bar's website and perform manual searches? There's no result when I simply Googled for the name.

Normally, you would determine where the lawyer's office was located and search the bar records of that state.
It would be quite unusual for a lawyer to have no online presence whatsoever, even if some of the search results are outdated.

Isn't a lawyer required to be admitted to the bar in the jurisdiction where they're practicing?

You and no @littleadv - you might be a NY layer but practice on a pro hoc vicae basis in an oaklahoma case. Or you might be admitted in 5 or 6 Bar associations.

@littleadv Yes. But as Trish notes, if you are admitted in one U.S. jurisdiction and affiliate with a local counsel, you can be admitted pro hac elsewhere. There are also some kinds of interjurisdictional practice tasks that don't require admission in every relevant jurisdiction. For example, if you are a NYS lawyer with an NYC client who is evaluating where to build their next factory you can compare and contrast the laws of states where you aren't admitted to practice to help your client make that choice.

Right, but in the first case there's still a local counsel for supervision, and in the second case the attorney is in fact licensed in NYC.... Just saying

@littleadv But arguably, in the second case the attorney is providing opinions about non-NYS law where the lawyer isn't admitted to practice. Still, none of that detracts from the notion that the lawyer needs to be admitted somewhere in the U.S. to be a real U.S. lawyer, and would almost surely show up in an internet search if the lawyer was. I show up in maybe half a dozen lawyer directories with which I've had no contact, and in public records such as appellate court argument videos, in addition to search results that not every lawyer would have like publications.
